# Show foreign key in DJANGO REST

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

My first question here. Glad to be part of this community.
My question: I'm using python3 and the django rest framework to create an API. 
I have the following models:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    # id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.BigIntegerField()
    updated_at = models.BigIntegerField()
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    first_release_date = models.BigIntegerField()
    category = models.SmallIntegerField()
    cover = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ReleaseDate(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.BigIntegerField()
    updated_at = models.BigIntegerField()
    category = models.SmallIntegerField()
    platform = models.SmallIntegerField()
    date = models.BigIntegerField()
    region = models.SmallIntegerField()
    y = models.SmallIntegerField()
    m = models.SmallIntegerField()
    human = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

To create a serializer for the Game and ReleaseDate I'd do:

```
class ReleaseDateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ReleaseDate
        fields = '__all__'


class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = '__all__'
```

... and this would provide me with:

```
[
    {
        "name": "God of war",
        "url": "efgsd"
    },
    {
        "name": "Uncharted",
        "url": "sgdfd"
    },
    {
        "name": "Fortnight",
        "url": "efgsd"
    }
]
```

How would I go about to get this, ie:

```
[
    {
        "name": "God of war",
        "url": "efgsd"
        "release_dates": "[
           {..},
           {..}
         ]"
    },
    {
        "name": "Uncharted",
        "url": "sgdfd"
        "release_dates": "[
           {..},
           {..}
         ]"
    },
    {
        "name": "Fortnight",
        "url": "efgsd"
        "release_dates": "[
           {..},
           {..}
         ]"
    }
]
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [drf documentation for nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example), you'd have to do something like

Modify your `game` FK in your `ReleaseDate` model to include a `related_name` attribute `release_date`

```
class ReleaseDate(models.Model):
     game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name = 'release_date', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

and then update your `GameSerializer` like so

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    release_date = ReleaseDateSerializer(many = True, read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ('name', 'url', 'release_date', )
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you